# spl_autoload_register issue

Tags: php

I don't get why I get this error

```
Fatal error: Class 'ImageJpg' not found
```

Here is the code that I use

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    if(file_exists($class))
    {
        include $class.'.php';
    }
});

$n = new ImageJpg();
```

File ImageJpg.php is in the same dir with the code above.

Here is the content of ImageJpg.php

```
<?php
class ImageJpg
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Image from jpg called';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a class named ImageJpg in your ImageJpg.php file? And does file exist?
Try this:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    if(file_exists($class.'.php'))
    {
        include $class.'.php';

        if (!class_exists($class))
        {
            die('required class not present');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        die('file not found');
    }
});
```

Comment: I see now. So the problem must have been the one xdazz pointed out (and I fixed that in my code).

Answer (score 2):

```
if(file_exists($class))
{
    include $class.'.php';
}
```

Should be

```
if(file_exists($class.'.php'))
{
    include $class.'.php';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with file_exists also and I was debugging for like 2 hours and nothing happen even after I've searched all around and also on web. At the end it was a typo: instead `userController.php` it was `userControlller.php` the actual file.
Check again (in this order):

1. Make SURE you don't have typo in your file name (either PHP or file system)
2. Check your path - `ROOT` and/or use `getcwd()`
3. Temporary print / log your checks to make sure everything matches
4. Avoid human error :)